# Phonegap - How to store text in a checklist app, even after app closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I am planning to make my first app using Phonegap.

What I want to make is a checklist. To add an item to the checklist, the user enters an item into an input field. My issue is that I don't know how I could save those items there, even after the app is closed and opened. I want those items to stay in the checklist until the user deletes them using a delete button.

I know a little about HTML5 local storage, cookies and databases. I believe I need to use HTML5 local storage? I would like my app to be used **offline** **(wifi off)** and I don't know what storage system needs internet and doesn't need internet.

Appreciate any help, I may add addition questions to this :^)

Answer (score 0):

I have used HTML5 localstorage to make a checklist app myself.

With a little knowledge of HTML and Javascript you should be able to teach yourself how to accomplish this task by learning [Localstorage from w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: I used AngularJS to grab all my data from a JSON file and propagate the DOM with names and images of things on the checklist.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with LocalStorage. It allows you to persist information offline, an even after the app/browser closes or device is rebooted.

LocalStorage only saves strings, so if you want to save other types of data, you can use JSON.stringify(yourvariable); and JSON.parse(localStorage.yourvariable);

For example:

```
var yourlist = {item1: "firstitem", item1status: "enabled" };
```

is a Javascript object, so if you want to save it:

```
localStorage.list = JSON.stringify(yourlist);
```

and then you want to retreive it later:

```
var thesamelist = JSON.parse(localStorage.list);
```

That's the basic usage, there are many more features that you can find in the documentation. Good luck with your app :)